# Measuring SQL execution time in PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

MySQL has a performance_schema database that allows one to capture SQL statement execution time data in a table (e.g. performance_schema.events_statements_history_long ; [useful MySQL link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-timing.html)).

I was wondering if a similar set of tools existed in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Can you explain in short what "instrumented event timing" is, for those not familiar with?

Comment: Instrumentation is added to the server source code  to determine the beginning and end of certain events or jobs. In MySQL events are simply named database objects containing one or many SQL statements to be executed. What I'm trying to do is find a way to measure the start and end time of SQL statements once I plug them into the command line for psql (or pgAdmin).

Comment: `\timing` issued in the psql console window at the start of your session is probably a good start.

Comment: Check out the `pg_stats_statement` module: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a reasonably easy way to do this, but you can:

1. Log slow queries
2. Use [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) to see where the query is actually spending its time.

You *could* probably store plans in the database somehow but I am not quite sure how this would be done (maybe with a pl/perl function?).  You'd have to roll your own solution though.

Storing plans in the database however is not easy.  One of the huge problems that you will have is getting the recursive structure right so you can query it.  A simple approach might be to take a JSON format and store that, or store XML.

Comment: But isn't that exactly what pg_stat_statements is doing? (storing that information in the database)

Comment: hmmmm  I misread "in" for "on."  Yes, pg_stat_statements is an option, provided you don't need to be able to report on which tables were hit.

Comment: Coupled with the other suggestions, you can also use csv logging and one of the Foreign Data Wrappers to read in the db logs to the table: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-CSVLOG